# Creating new slot in RasterLayer using R?

Tags: raster, r

I am trying to use a [function from a package in R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lulcc/versions/1.0.4/topics/ObsLulcRasterStack) that requires a slot in my raster/stack with time information. Ideally, this simple code should do the trick:

```
lu_2012 <- raster("f2012lcs_new.rst")
lu_2012@t <- 2012
```

But it doesn't, since this is not the right way to create slots:

```
lu_2012@t <- 2012
Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  : 
  ‘t’ is not a slot in class “RasterLayer”
```

Is there a way to create a new slot in a RasterLayer/stack like that?

Comment: There is already a slot "z" intended for this. I have used it for storing dates and all you have to do to access it is x$z <- ...

Comment: Wow... So simple! Brilliant! thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this you have to ceate a new class which is a subclass of `RasterLayer`:

```
> traster = setClass("traster", contains="RasterLayer", slots=c(t="numeric"))
```

Create a standard raster - it has no `t` slot:

```
> r =raster()
> r@t=99
Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  : 
  ‘t’ is not a slot in class “RasterLayer”
```

Convert to my `traster` class:

```
> r = as(r, "traster")
> r@t=99
>
```

and it does have a `t` slot. A raster extended this way should still work as a normal `RasterLayer` everywhere else.